# Dynamic associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using Rails 4.2.1, Ruby 2.2.1 and PostgreSQL 9.3

How should I implement complex associations between models below?

Region have many Products.

For each Region Administrator can define set of product Attributes. E.g. `type: ['one', 'two']`, `size: ['small', 'medium', 'large']` and so on. And can customize list of possible values. Also he can add after some time brand new attribute with list of possible values.

So, for example, region1 can have following attributes: `type: ['one', 'two', 'three','four']`, `custom_attr: ['foo', 'bar']`.
region2: `size: ['s','m','l','xl']`, `custom_attr1: ['f','b']`

And when User create a Product in region1, he should see something similar to matrix with checkboxes (already checked some):

```
|               |new_product|
|type.one       |           |
|type.two       |    X      |
|custom_attr.foo|    X      |
|custom_attr.bar|    X      |

submit_button
```

New product in region2:

```
|              |new_product|
|size.s        |    X      |
|size.m        |    X      |
|size.l        |           |
|size.xl       |           |
|custom_attr1.f|           |
|custom_attr1.b|    X      |

submit_button
```

Comment: Try using enums http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html. You can create products based on enums declared.

Comment: I need to add attributes dynamically in runtime

Comment: https://github.com/devmynd/hstore_accessor

Comment: Better to add 3 tables, products, attributes, attributes values. `products` can have many attributes, `attributes` can have many `attribute values`..